# webrtc video stream and screen share library

Tags: video, streaming, screen-scraping, webrtc

I need a WebRTC based product (open source or commercial licensed) which supplies following requirements.

- Screen share, video and audio stream
- Work with Google Chrome,Firefox, Support IE if possible
- IOS Library Support

So what my goal is

i am going to build a system which allows users that communicate between each other via ASP.NET website and Ipad / Iphone application by designated support capabilities. I found some libraries over internet but they dont support screen share or have both capabilities separately.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [RTCMultiConnection](https://github.com/muaz-khan/WebRTC-Experiment/tree/master/RTCMultiConnection); however, it doesn't support iOS devices. You can try chrome beta or firefox on android devices though.

It is a single solution for all RTCWeb APIs!

Comment: Thanks for comment. I am going to check but i definitely need IOS support. IOS  is the key for my project. :)

Answer (score 0):

I know it's kind of outdated, but our product meets all your needs: http://www.addlive.com.