# Complete Webrtc solution supporting A/V text chat and file transfer

Tags: text, chat, file-transfer, webrtc

I am looking for a webrtc solution that supports Audio, Video, text chat and file transfer. I have tried different solutions such as LiCode Lynckia, easyrtc, webrtc.io. But non of them is completed solution of webrtc. Any suggestion is highly appreciated.

Comment: Check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18865273/webrtc-video-stream-and-screen-share-library/18865871#18865871

Comment: I tried "Muaz Khan" webrtc-experiment. the problem with it is the file transferring. It chunks the file to very small unites (lesser than MTU) and send them over the network. I am not sure it is the best idea for file transferring. It generated over 900 chunks for a 750KB file to transfer and it took almost 10 minutes to transfer the file in a Local Network!

Answer (score 0):

**Disclaimer: I work at vLine**

Take a look at the [vLine API](https://vline.com/developer/docs/low_level_intro). We have a complete solution with all of the features that you're asking about (in addition to more such as presence) and it's backed by a globally distributed network for low-latency.

Answer (score 0):

You can also look at EasyRTC again. We've added a file share demo. You'll have to put the building blocks together but it is all there. Let us know how it works. I believe we can do quite large files.